A quadratic function question from a Olympiad practice test

This was the first question I encountered while giving the test . I always find trouble  in understanding the meaning of such question .
Can someone please explain the meaning or give a hint of this question , like what does it actually mean by if $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $f(a^2 -6b-1) =f(b^2+8)$ ?
and how can we find $f(2) , f(8)$ etc.

Assume that there exists real numbers $~r,s,t~$ with $~r \neq 0,~$ such that $~f(x) = rx^2 + sx + t.~$  Then see where the premise leads.  Note that you are not being asked to solve specifically for $~r,s,~t,~$ necessarily.  Instead, consider the specific fraction that you are being asked to evaluate.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

@CalvinLin FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Quadratic function.

@JohnOmielan Oh thanks! I realized what I did wrong. I thought that case wasn't possible at all, but didn't check the details.

By the way, in most dialects of English, the teacher gives the test, the students take the test.

Please avoid the use of pictures. Instead use MathJax to type the math in your question.

Write the quadratic function $f$ as follows: $f=R(x-S)^2+T$. It turns out that the parameters $R$ and $T$ are irrelevant. One might just well take $R=1$ and $T=0$. Now $f$ is a parabole, symmetric around the value $x = S$. Given that $f(a) = f(b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are distinct values, we can conclude that the solution is: $a = S +c$, $b = S - c$ where $c$ is an arbitrary value. Furthermore we see that $a+b=2S$.
We now turn to the second identity: $f(a^2 - 6b-1) = f(b^2+8)$. It is tempting to analyse this expression in the same way as above, i.e. to assume that the two arguments are symmetric around $S$. I have tried this, and it does not work. The resulting expression is awkward and has no obvious solutions. Luckily, there is a different -and much simpler- approach. What if the two arguments are simply identical? This would obviously solve the equation immediately! Indeed, this works. We get: $a^2 = b^2+6b+9$, hence $a = \pm (b+3)$. Taking the minus sign, we arrive at $a+b=-3$.
Combining these results, we see that when $S = -3/2$ any solution of the first equation is also a solution of the second equation, as required. Therefore we can conclude that $f = R(x+3/2)^2+T$.
Finally, $\frac {f(8)-f(2)}{f(2)-f(1)} = \frac{361-49}{49-25} = \frac{312}{24} = 13$

Mind if I ask why $R$ and $T$ are irrelevant?

Because only $S$ determines the relation between $a$ and $b$. $R$ and $T$ remain unknown. And in the final calculation of the ratio, both $R$ and $T$ drop out.

I presume you understand the definitions of the terms. If so, a good start to understanding the problem is to study the conditions. What do they imply? What could cause them to be true?

When do we have $f(a) = f(b)$?
Fact: For a given quadratic function, there exists a $c$ such that  $f(a) = f(b)$ for distinct reals iff $a+b = c$.

As an explicit example, for the quadratic function $g(x) = x^2$, we can show that $g(a) = g(b)$ iff $ a + b = 0$, so our $ c = 0$.
Can you determine $c$ from the coefficients of $g(x)$?
As an example of an application of this fact, let's show that the denominator $f(2) - f(1) \neq 0$.
Suppose not, then $f(2) = f(1)$, so our $c = 2 + 1 = 3$.
Applying  $ a = 2, b=1$ to the given condition, we get that  $f(-3) = f(a^2 - 6b - 1 ) = f(b^2 + 8 ) = f(9)$, but $ -3 + 9 \neq c $, hence we have a contradiction.

Any statement of the form $X \implies Y$ can be read as meaning "any time $X$ is true, $Y$ is also guaranteed to be true".
The given condition:
$$f(a) = f(b) \implies f(a^2 - 6b - 1) = f(b^2 + 8)$$
means that if we try a bunch of different values of $a$ and $b$, then if we find a pair such that $f(a) = f(b)$, then we will also notice that $f(a^2 - 6b - 1) = f(b^2 + 8)$. For example, suppose that we determined that $f(1) = 3$, and also $f(6) = 3$. Then we can set $a = 1, b = 6$ and hence conclude that $f(-36) = f(44)$, whatever value that may take.
Because we're also told that $f$ is a quadratic, we know that it has a certain symmetry to it, so the values of $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $f(a) = f(b)$ are related somehow - and that same symmetry must also apply to $a^2 - 6b - 1$ and $b^2 + 8$. By abusing that symmetry, we will be able to find something out that will help us find the value of the given fraction.

Since no one else offered a primitive solution, I will do so.
Since $~f(x)~$ is a quadratic (polynomial), it can be expressed as
$$f(x) = rx^2 + sx + t ~: ~r,s,t \in \Bbb{R}, ~r \neq 0. \tag1 $$
You are given that
$$f(a) = f(b) \implies f(a^2 - 6b - 1) = f(b^2 + 8). \tag2 $$
You are then asked to numerically compute
$$\frac{f(8) - f(2)}{f(2) - f(1)}. \tag3 $$

(3) above, which represents the sole requirement of the problem, does not (necessarily) require that explicit values for $~r,s,t~$ be found.  At this point, you don't know whether this will be necessary.
What is known, is that a numerical value for (3) above must be determined.
Expressing (3) above in terms of $~r,s,t~$ you are being asked to compute
$$\frac{[ ~64r + 8s + t ~] - [ ~4r + 2s + t ~]}{[ ~4r + 2s + t ~] - [ ~r + s + t ~]} = \frac{60r + 6s}{3r + s}. \tag4 $$
Then:

If $~s = 0,~$ then (4) above will compute to $~20.$

If $~s \neq 0,~$ then (4) above can be computed by determining the ratio of the two non-zero variables $~r,s.$


So, the entire problem is reduced to using the implication in (2) above to resolve the two bullet points above.
Analytically, a 2nd degree polynomial is never strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, throughout $~\Bbb{R}.~$  What this implies is that there will always be situations where $~f(a) = f(b)~$ and $~a \neq b.$
So, without loss of generality, the implication in (2) above will be explored under the assumption that $~a \neq b~$ and $~f(a) = f(b).$

The LHS of (2) above may be expressed as the premise that
$$ra^2 + sa = rb^2 + sb \iff r(a^2 - b^2) + s(a-b) = 0 \iff r(a + b) + s = 0. \tag 5$$
Now, to ease the computations, set $~u = a^2 - 6b - 1, ~v = b^2 + 8.~$ Then the RHS of (2) may be expressed as
$$ru^2 + su = rv^2 + sv \iff r(u^2 - v^2) + s(u - v) = 0. \tag6 $$
So, the entire problem has been reduced to using the fact that (5) above implies (6) above to either

Prove that $~s~$ must equal $~0.$

Alternatively, if $~s \neq 0,~$ determine the ratio between $~r~$ and $~s.$


I am going to break the analysis down into case work, depending on whether $~u = v.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~u \neq v}$
Then
$$r(a + b) + s = 0$$
implies that
$$r(u^2 - v^2) + s(u - v) = 0 \iff r(u + v) + s = 0. $$
Therefore
$$r(a + b) = r(u + v) \iff (a + b) = (u + v) \iff $$
$$(a + b) = [~a^2 - 6b - 1 ~] + [ ~b^2 + 8 ~] \iff $$
$$a^2 - a + b^2 - 7b + 7 = 0 \iff $$
$$\left( ~a - \frac{1}{2} ~\right)^2 + \left( ~b - \frac{7}{2} ~\right)^2 = \frac{11}{2}. \tag7 $$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~u = v}$
Then
$$r(a + b) + s = 0$$
implies that
$$[~a^2 - 6b - 1 ~] = [ ~b^2 + 8 ~] \iff a^2 = b^2 + 6b + 9 = (b + 3)^2 \iff $$
$$a^2 = (b+3)^2. \tag8 $$

So, the entire problem has been reduced to either

Determining that $s~$ must equal $~0,~$

Determining the ratio between $~r,s~$ under the assumption that $~s \neq 0.~$


What you have is that $~r(a+b) + s = 0~$ implies that either (7) or (8) above must hold.
Suppose that $~s = 0.~$ Then $~r(a + b) = 0 \implies (a + b) = 0 \implies a^2 = b^2.$
This is inconsistent with both (7) above and (8) above.
So, the assumption that $~s = 0,~$ is not tenable.
Edit
To amplify here, if $~s = 0,~$ you will always be able to find at least one ordered pair $~(a,b)~$ such that $~a \neq b,~$ and such that $~a + b = 0,~$ and such that both (7) above and (8) above fail to be satisfied.
Therefore, you have that $~r,s~$ are two fixed but unknown non-zero constants, which implies that the ratio between $~r,s~$ is some fixed constant.
Therefore, there must exist some fixed non-zero real number $~k~$ such that
$rk + s = 0.$
Further, you have that $~r(a+b) + s = 0~$ must imply that either (7) or (8) is true.  However, you can now conclude that $~r(a+b) + s = 0~$ if and only if $~(a+b)~$ is always equal to the constant $~k.$
The only way that one of (7) or (8) above will always be satisfied, whenever $~(a + b) = k,~$ where $~k~$ is some fixed but unknown constant, is if [from (8) above]
$$a = - (b + 3) \implies (a + b) = -3.$$
Therefore, you can now conclude that
$$3r = s.$$
Therefore, you have that
$$\frac{f(8) - f(2)}{f(2) - f(1)} = \frac{60r + 6s}{3r + s} = \frac{26s}{2s} = 13.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

The only way that one of (7) or (8) above will always be satisfied, whenever $~(a + b) = k,~$ where $~k~$ is some fixed but unknown constant, is if $~(a + b) = -3.~$

This deserves some amplification.
Suppose $~k \neq -3~$ and $~r(a+b) + s = 0.~$
This implies that the implication that (7) above or (8) above must hold, for any values of $~a,b~$ such that $~(a + b) = k.~$
Since $~k \neq -3,~$ you will always be able to find at least one ordered pair $~(a,b)~$ such that $~a \neq b,~$ and such that $~(a + b) = k \neq -3,~$ and where both (7) above and (8) above fail to be satisfied.

If $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a\neq b$ then $b=2m-a\neq m$ where $m$ is the abscissa of the vertex of the parabola $y=f(x)=\alpha(x-m)^2+\beta$, as noticed by M. Wind.
$f(a^2-6b-1)=f(b^2+8)$ means either

$$a^2-6b-1=b^2+8\implies\\ (4m+6)a=(2m+3)^2$$ for all $m\neq a\in\Bbb R$. Hence, $m=-\frac32.$
$$a^2-6b-1=2m-(b^2+8)\implies\\
2a^2+(6-4m)a+4m^2-4m+7=0$$
for all $m\neq a\in\Bbb R$ which is not possible for any $m.$

So, $m=-\frac32$ and
$$\frac{f(8)-f(2)}{f(2)-f(1)}=\frac{(
\alpha(8+\tfrac32)^2+\beta)-
(\alpha(2+\tfrac32)^2+\beta)
}{(\alpha(2+\tfrac32)^2+\beta)-(\alpha(8+\tfrac32)^2+\beta)}\\
=13.$$
